# What is the difference between the model and session in spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, model-view-controller, controller

Currently I am learning the spring MVC framework, I wanted to know what is the difference between using the Model interface, `request.setAttribute()` and session(HttpSession) object. We can use the model interface in a Spring MVC controller to save things, where as we can do the exact same with session and `request.setAttribute()`, when should I use either of these and what are their differences?

Comment: Go through this [link](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/)

Answer (score 2):

MODEL: In general this model is associated with view. You prepare data from some business logic & populate that data into model. Spring will help you render those model values into view. Once spring display view with model values on front-end that model will no more available on controller. It means same model is not available throughout multiple requests.

Session: Session hold the values for cross requests for single user. Http protocol is stateless so we maintain state using session. Each time user requests to the server, server treats the request as the new request. So we need to maintain the state of an user to recognize to particular user. 
To recognize a user session is used.